# Почему не работает проведение и запись документа 1С?

Tags: 1с

Есть пользователь 1С. У него не работает проведение и запись документа. Как это можно исправить?

Я скопировал пользователя, все профили и ограничения по организациям. Когда я попробовал за скопированного пользователя создать документ и провести его, все сработало и ошибок не было. Но почему у него работает, а у основного нет, я ведь все скопировал.

Права перепроверил, у обоих есть доступ на проведение и редактирование этого вида документа.

UPD1:
Сейчас зашел за основного пользователя в документ. Почему-то неактивны кнопки записи и проведения, но роль на доступ к записи и проведению у пользователя есть.

Comment: Уточните что такое выгруженный документ ?

Comment: @santavital зря написал про выгруженный, похоже разницы с обычным документом нет

Comment: Поправил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первым делом следует убедиться, что документ в ***текущем периоде*** ! Если это так, (не прошлым месяцем документ) проверить ***Дату запрета редактирования***, общую и для конкретного пользователя.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло. Вы не знаете, где еще может быть проблема?

Comment: Опишите подробно: Что за конфигурация, что за документ !

Comment: Конфигурация с поддержкой, документ - отражение зарплаты в бух. учете

Comment: Проблемы не было месяц назад, может можно как-то посмотреть, что было раньше

Comment: Опишите подробно как копировали пользователя